# Announcement: AI generated content banned on Worldbuilding

Tags: discussion, rules

Community discussion has been taking place on WB Meta concerning our position on AI generated content:

[Should we ban posts using ChatGPT or similar software?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9991/30492)

Because of the outcome of the discussion and the considerable workload dealing with these posts by Community and elected Moderators, the following decision has been made:

---

There is now a **complete ban on the use of ChatGPT and AI generated content** on Worldbuilding.

This ban involves:

1. Deletion of all ChatGPT or other AI content, whether acknowledged as such or not
2. Moderator message for initial occurrence, if minor in scope
3. Seven day Suspension for subsequent occurrence, or initial occurrence if larger in scope, and then the usual escalation of penalties for further infractions

---

Note that it is the moderator team's opinion that the use of Grammarly and spell checking tools to correct grammar errors and spelling errors are not AI generated content - using those to improve your own written posts' grammar or to correct spelling errors are not forbidden, we are specifically barring the use of ChatGPT and other AIs as the sole source of generating answer content.

Comment: All hail Dorothy! The wicked witch is dead!