# Do we want to enable a banner stating that AI content is banned on WB.SE?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, stackexchange

There is a [post on Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera) stating that it is now possible for SE sites to enable a banner that states that AI content is banned or must be cited.

Since [AI Content is banned on Worldbuilding Stackexchange](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10067/75), do we want to enable the banner stating that AI content is banned on Worldbuildiing.Stackexchange.com, similar to the image below?

[image]

If you want the banner, upvote the YES answer below.

If you don't want the banner, upvote the NO answer below.

In case you want to explain the yes/no, leave a comment under the answer.

Comment: How commonly are AI answers showing in the report queue? I can't say I've encountered them much but that may very well just have been diligent moderating (for which you are greatly appreciated).

Comment: @KeizerHarm We've handled a few.  I've had to ban a user who spammed AI answers.  It happens... and it gets dealt with.

Comment: I really wish they made the banner red. I honestly didn't get that *that* is the banner until ploughing through several links looking for images and finally expanding one. Light blue is NOT a warning colour. But yes, we should implement.

Answer (score 35):

YES, I want the banner as explained in the question.

Comment: 119 views and 8 votes between the answers. Is it possible to know how many of those views were actual users vs. Google-esque bots? I miss the community ads. I'm convinced they increased participation.

Comment: @JBH the views don't correspond to individual users, either. Single user can generate more than one view.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks! And that just makes everything worse. It's really a shame that participation in Meta has dropped so much.

Comment: I'm a frequent user of GPT 4 turbo, which is still in beta. It is damned good, but it is not good enough to be used to answer questions that require critical thinking and careful consideration. It is my sincere belief that A.I. generated content should be banned. I vote "YES", with the reservation, that it should be permissible to use A.I. as a tool, e.g. help translating an answer or a question that a user has written in their native language.

Comment: @JBH it's not exactly participation, but can be random users, sometimes from completely other sites who have not enough context or good enough stack of pros and cons to immediately vote here.

Comment: This banner has now been enabled.

Answer (score -1):

NO, I don't want the banner as explained in the question.